# Reconfigure output for Matching function Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm am matching column A in both sheets

SheetA = FindReplace SheetB = Test

If a match exists then post back the value to the right of the match cell in SheetA to the same row in SheetB but in Column B

The ranges in the matching columns may be different in size

It came from a question I asked here

[Match text strings of two columns on different sheet and post back using google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176453/match-text-strings-of-two-columns-on-different-sheet-and-post-back-using-google)

I need to alter it slightly so that when a match is `not` found it post back the value being searched with from sheetB which is `dataB[b][0]` or is it `b` I am confused here

I thought this would be relatively easy (and maybe it is) but I can not figure it out

One of the things I tried was to change this
`if (b != res.length - 1) res.push([""]);` to `if (b != res.length - 1) res.push([b]);`

Also

```
for (var a in dataWith) {
          if (dataWith[a][0] == dataIN[b][0]) {res.push([dataPB[a][0]]);}
          else {res.push([dataWith[b][0]]);}
      }
```

This partialy works but give way to many ruturns

I hope this was clear

Thanks for any help with this

Right now the output is

```
MatchedCol
matchedFoundValue
matchedFoundValue
matchedFoundValue

matchedFoundValue


matchedFoundValue
.
.
.
```

The result I need:

```
MatchedCol
matchedFoundValue
matchedFoundValue
matchedFoundValue
SearchWithvalue (no match)
matchedFoundValue
SearchWithvalue (no match)
SearchWithvalue (no match)
matchedFoundValue
```

.
.
.

```
function MatchColumnsAlternate(){
// gets spreadsheet A and the range of data
var sheetA =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FindReplace");
var dataA = sheetA.getRange(2, 1, sheetA.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

// gets spreadsheet B and the range of data
var sheetB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
var dataB = sheetB.getRange(2, 1, sheetB.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

// Added
var res = [];
for (var b in dataB) {
for (var a in dataA) {
  if (dataA[a][0] == dataB[b][0]) res.push([dataA[a][1]]);
}
if (b != res.length - 1) res.push([""]);
}
sheetB.getRange(2, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the output data? When in [your shared sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176453/match-text-strings-of-two-columns-on-different-sheet-and-post-back-using-google), there are no data for ``H13, H14, H16, H17`` in "FindReplace". If you want to give the data to output at this situation, please modify ``if (b != res.length - 1) res.push([""]);`` to ``if (b != res.length - 1) res.push(["SearchWithvalue (no match)"]);``. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to think of your solution.

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try changing**

```
if (b != res.length - 1) res.push([""]);
```

**with**

```
if (b != res.length - 1) res.push([dataB[b][0]]);
```

**Result**

[image]